# How to insert chart copied from Excel with .PasteSpecial method in PowerPoint as SVG?

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, powerpoint

I am copying a chart from Excel with the below code:

```
oChartObject.Chart.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture)
```

Now I want to insert this chart in PowerPoint as SVG image. I am using .PasteSpecial but the PpPasteDataType enum does not seem to accept SVG (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.View.PasteSpecial)

```
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(PowerPoint.PpPasteDataType.SeeWebLinkToMicrosoft)
```

But when manually calling the paste special dialog in PowerPoint I can choose to paste an image from Excel as SVG (see screenshot).[image]

My question: how can I paste a chart copied from Excel as SVG to PowerPoint?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SVG is a comparatively new format in Office. It hasn't been added to the VBA object model yet. Instead, try using *ppPasteEnhancedMetafile*. This pastes as **EMF**, a vector format that has better support from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. EMF quality is quite blurry compared to the SVG format even though it is supposed to be vector based.

Comment: I'm not seeing any such result here. After pasting, select the chart and choose _Picture Format>Group>Ungroup_. The EMF should ungroup and be converted to Office drawing objects.

Comment: Insert a picture and scale down the size. If you then compare the fonts between a SVG and the EMF you should see that the font is much sharper in the SVG.

Comment: Sorry, tried that and both formats look exactly the same using Microsoft 365 for Windows Version 2108 (Build 14326.20404 Click-to-Run). But the point is moot: Paste Special with the SVG format is not in the object model, so you'll have to use some other format.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I am on office 2019 so maybe they improved it in O365. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Even if PowerPoint.PpPasteDataType.ppPasteSVG does not exist in the object model, you should still be able to pass the Integer value as an argument in PasteSpecial(). The question is, what is that Integer value? **The answer is 12.**  You have to use Copy() instead of CopyPicture(), though.

Unfortunately, it does not appear that this trick is available for Word, even though the PasteSpecial dialog in Word supports pasting as SVG.  Likely an oversight by Microsoft.

Comment: This is a bummer! I really needed a wdPasteSVG format. I have a Word document with hundreds of embedded Word drawings that need to be converted to SVG for processing by a downstream toolchain. Now I'll need to manually copy/paste-special them, and there's hundreds of them...